# BIOS not booting from hard disk, Ubuntu CD boot to hard disk works

Tags: linux, boot, bios, grub, ubuntu-12.04

After copying my Ubuntu installation from one disk to another (copy, update `fstab`, `update-grub`, `grub-install /dev/sda1`), the Ubuntu CD option boots from the first hard disk (`localboot 0x80`) – it boots the system just fine. The BIOS doesn't boot from the hard disk though.

I have a Compaq 6730s. BIOS settings: UEFI is off, SATA is AHCI.

I do not have this problem using the old hard disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a boot flag to a partition.

Run `fdisk` and command "a".